# MongoDB 3+ on Pi 3

Tags: mongodb

I recently tried to run the binaries for mongodb from the website of mongopi without much succes... Despite setting the path as follow

```
export PATH=/home/pi/mongo34_arm64_rPi3/bin:$PATH
```

I am getting the following

> Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service not found.

Has anyone managed to run mongodb 3+ on pi 3 lately here ?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stack Exchange. You need to provide more details: a link to the instructions you're following and the steps you actually followed. Right now, the only thing I know you did was changing your system path, but if you didn't download the binaries then this would obviously not work. If you're having any doubts about how this website works (what kind of questions and answers we have), take a look at the [site's tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour).